# What is the best way to integrate a 'parental permission' requirement during registration?

Tags: usability, forms, registration

I am currently making a signup page for children age <16 to sign up to play in charity football matches. Due to legalities, parental permission is required for each signup for the football match. However, I am not sure what would be the best way to fulfil this requirement.

I was told by the organization that simply having a checkbox is not enough. Has anyone else ever made a similar form?

> [image]

My current design offers a form parents need to fill in and then upload before they (or the child) can hit send. However, I feel like this is kind of too much effort on the parents' behalf and I'm looking for a solution that makes it both easy and 'OK' from a legal perspective.

Comment: What is 'legal' is probably different for each country and each situation. As I imagine the legal issues are not really something that can be compromised with I would speak to the legal department directly and try to find out the minimum requirements from them. Do they need a paper form? If so, why? How do they verify the parental status even with this? Is there another way they could collect this information that you could replicate digitally?

Comment: Yes it does depend on the country. I was told by legal that in my country (NL) children/teenagers are not able to give permission nor can they be approached for commercial goals. The latter can be circumvented due to this being a charity thing, but the former still stands. At this point I'm just unsure what passes the bar for a reasonable guess that the parent gave permission. I'll head back to legal for clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fellow Dutchie I might have an answer for you. I've had to dive into our country's IT law when building a webshop that sells a few alcoholic drinks.
The question was, could we be fined if we sold to minors? It turned out that by only showing a message that said that we don't sell to minors and by buying alcohol, they confirm they're of age, was enough.

A small search on parental permission returns somewhat the same. A checkbox would suffice. It's all about how much risk you would want to take.
If the parents want to cancel the registration (because their kid signed up without their permission) you can't bill any administrative costs or similar costs. You can keep any sign up fee they already payed.

Adding the permission sheet upload option would reduce the chances of false registration, but it might also add an extra barrier that might scare off kids, because it's too much effort.

Here are some source (in Dutch):
https://blog.iusmentis.com/2007/11/19/forumlid-worden-als-minderjarige-vereist-toestemming-ouders/
https://hostingrecht.nl/diensten/juridisch-advies/contracten/minderjarige-klanten/